# Format string representation of float according to english locale with Clojure

Tags: clojure

The locale on my machine is sv_SE.utf8, I want format to follow the conventions of en_GB.utf8 instead when formatting strings. Currently

```
(format "%f" 0.1) ; => 0,1
```

instead of

```
(format "%f" 0.1) ; => 0.1
```

It seems like I can't pass a locale to format. Is there any other way of working around this problem? I still want to keep using format due to its other capabilities.

Comment: Apparently not, [Tower](https://github.com/ptaoussanis/tower#localization) has `fmt-str` for this purpose.

Comment: Perhaps you can also turn the problem on its head, since there are many locale-dependent methods in the JDK: start the JVM with locale `en_GB`, `-Duser.language=en -Duser.country=GB` (with Leiningen: `:jvm-opts ["-Duser.language=en" "-Duser.country=GB"]`), then provide your own `format` function that takes a locale for those cases where you actually need locale-specific formatting.

Comment: Yes that would be a solution, but of course I'd much prefer an environment independent solution which doesn't affect all other language related functions of the program.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This works for me (my laptop default locale is set to `fr-FR`, France!):

```
(import java.util.Locale)
; => java.util.Locale

(defn my-format [fmt n & [locale]]
  (let [locale (if locale (Locale. locale)
                          (Locale/getDefault))]
    (String/format locale fmt (into-array Object [n]))))

; => #'dev/my-format

(my-format "%f" 0.1)
; => "0,100000"

(my-format "%f" 0.1 "en-GB")
; => "0.100000"
```

Any good?

Comment: Yup! With some minor modifications we could make a `my-format` which takes an arbitrary number of arguments like `format`.